# How long does Facebook take to verify an account? 

Tags: facebook, verification

How long does it take Facebook to verify an account when you submit your ID? It's been nine (9) days now.

I submitted it with the online form and got an email back immediately saying I needed to submit it, and if I already submitted it that I needed to reply, submitting it again. So I replied to the e-mail with the scan of my driver's license attached.

I signed up using Chris, instead of Christopher. I also changed my birth date by 5 days, as I didn't think they needed my exact birth date.

Is that why they are not replying? - Using the shortened version of my name, and a slightly off birth date?

My account is sitting there, with my picture, and I can't access it. I had a friend check, and he can see it - read the info and bio, and sent a friend request. That request showed up in my email.

This was a new account. I got the "roadblock" page right off - I sent one friend request, and tried to follow that up by sending the person a message.

I have to say I'm not very impressed with Facebook. Pretty bad first impression.

Comment: If you needed to verify who you are, then why provide them with false birth date?

Comment: I laid out some background information for you, but I will need more information (for example did the roadblock link look like this :`facebook.com/checkpoint` or `facebook.com/roadblock/` to give a real answer (see the fine print in the answer).

Comment: @Barry.  I signed up with a birth date a couple days off.  I gave them the correct one in the verification process.

Comment: @phwd:  It was the ../roadblock URL.

Comment: Sorry I did not followup with this, did you get through with the process?

Comment: I'm hit with the same thing. It's been 3 days. How long do they need to verify an account? I didnt receive any mails after submitting though, so I'm like waiting in the dark not knowing if things are progressing.

Comment: Did this ever get resolved, and how long did it take? I've waited more than a month with no reply.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from the beginning, at the Facebook sign up page, there is the following

> Facebook requires all users to provide
>   their real date of birth to encourage
>   authenticity and provide only
>   age-appropriate access to content. You
>   will be able to hide this information
>   from your profile if you wish, and its
>   use is governed by the Facebook
>   Privacy Policy.

This takes care of the birthday issue.

For the nickname, there is the following,

> Please note that Facebook account
>   names must adhere to the following
>   authenticity standards: Your full
>   first and last name must be listed.
>   Initials cannot stand in place of your
>   full name. Nicknames can be listed if
>   they are a variation of your first or
>   last name, but only in the format
>   "First Name ‘Nickname’ Lastname."

Under [Facebook Terms](https://www.facebook.com/terms.php?ref=pf), here is what you need to be aware of

> **Registration and Account Security**
>
> Facebook users provide their real
>   names and information, and we need
>   your help to keep it that way. Here
>   are some commitments you make to us
>   relating to registering and
>   maintaining the security of your
>   account:
>
> - You will not provide any false personal information on Facebook, or
>     create an account for anyone other
>     than yourself without permission.
> - You will not create more than one personal profile.
> - If we disable your account, you will not create another one without our
>     permission.
> - You will keep your contact information accurate and up-to-date.

Knowing this and

- the *assumption* that disabling accounts are automated but appeals are manual
- the *assumption* that not entering your contact information *accurately* lead to this
- the *assumption* there are many, many, many appeals per day

9 days to even two weeks seems reasonable. Someone I knew was banned but appealed, it took a very long while but a well worded polite email plus some patience led to a renewal. This is not going to work for everyone obviously.

In your case, as noted on this appeal page for deactivated accounts (though not new accounts, I think the same process applies)

"Note that writing in and submitting your ID multiple times will not result in a faster response. Once you submit your initial request, it is placed in a queue and responded to accordingly. We appreciate your patience and apologize for any inconvenience this may cause."

<sub>There still is information that we need from you to decipher the information further, you said that it is a new account, yet you needed to confirm with a license. This sounds like a re-activation to me. It would be best if you could walk us through your entire process from sign up to roadblock with all relevant links and email correspondences that Facebook sent **(REMOVE ALL PERSONAL INFORMATION)**</sub>

Comment: Thanks.  How long do you think verification will take?  They have my full name and correct birth date.

Comment: Entire process:  Made new account. Filled out Bio, etc.  Sent one friend request, then clicked the link to send that same person a message.  I then got the roadblock url.  I didn't do anything else.  I immediately uploaded my ID.  It's been 11 days now.  I never had an account before.  I did fudge my DOB by 5 days when I signed up.  They can see the correct DOB on my license.  I submitted the form and uploaded my ID twice - one time I put my sign-up DOB on the form, the other time I used the one on my license.

Comment: @chris There is a still a step missing though, did you not get the confirmation email after signing up ?

Comment: I followed the link in the confirmation e-mail right after signing up.